# Why briangann-datatable-panel sorting is not working in grafana?

Tags: grafana, grafana-templating

I am working on grafana dashboard with briangann-datatable-panel plugin. Here I am trying to sort by total in ascending order but the sort is not working properly.

For Example:

```
Name        Total
------------------
user1       1
user2       1
user3       10
user4       105
user5       20
user6       3
user7       3
```

But I want output like this

```
Name        Total
------------------
user1       1
user2       1
user6       3
user7       3
user3       10
user5       20
user4       105
```

How can I fix this issue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks like you didn't set `Number` type for **Total** column.

Comment: yes I tried that also by using column styles

Comment: Probably you've hit  an open datatable-panel issue (https://github.com/briangann/grafana-datatable-panel/issues/117)